# read long double from a file, then write to another file

Tags: c++, file, atof

i have following part of code:

```
string v;

getline(linestream,v,' ');

double d=atof(v.c_str());

fprintf(writeFile3,"%f\n",(double)d);
```

but lets say first line has value 0.08012901 but d=0.080129 last 2 values are omitted, how can i get full double value?

Thank you

Comment: That cast isn't needed since `d` is already a `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that the decimal places are not stored in the `d`. It's just that `fprintf` only prints 6 decimal places by default. To print 8, try

```
fprintf(writeFile3, "%.8f\n", d);
```

You don't have to cast `d` as a `double` since it already is of type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the digits copied exactly, by far the easiest way to go is to just leave the digits in string form:

```
string v;

getline(instream, v, ' ');

outstream << v;
```

Almost anything that converts the digits to a `double`, then prints out the value has at least some chance of producing a result that's slightly different from the input.

Comment: or `fprintf(writeFile3, "%s\n", v.c_str());`

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the answer above that whatever you put after the variable call is what you will display.  By default C++ will show 6.

ie
fprintf(writeFile3, "%.3f\n", (double)d);  will display 3 decimal points at the end.  It will also pad so if there is possible for longer than 8 decimal places you will want to make it more than that.  That I know of you cannot set a flag to just display all decimal points.  It has to be explicit.